# Might Metamorphosis be Mix and Match?

Tags: biology, creature-design

There are several ways that an animal can change from one form to another. For example: pupae, gradual change, and the rapid transformation of frogs. Could a species with more than 2 life stages realistically use multiple of these methods to go between stages?

Comment: In your fictional world why do you think that it wouldn't be possible for a species with more than two life stages to grow and change in different ways?

Comment: @sphennings the forms of metamorphosis I have mentioned never coexist in nature, and seem completely opposed to each other

Comment: Fortunately nothing says that your world needs to be bounded by what exists in nature.

Comment: @IchthysKing I'm not sure it's true at all that various methods of metamorphosis don't coexist in the same species. Crustaceans start off in a pupal form, but once they reach their final shape, they will periodically moult and grow larger without changing their general shape, which would constitute two separate forms of growth, surely? I'm no biologist but I'm sure there are many more examples of similarly complex life cycles in the existing animal kingdom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## If nature selects it

When studying biology, one of the biggest advantages of creatures who undergo metamorphosis, especially in insects which undergo full metamorphosis, is precisely that the young and the adults do not occupy the same niche. Look at dragonflies for example. They're born predators and die as predators (eaten as prey many times, but predators nonetheless). Both its aquatic nymph and flying adult phases are carnivorous, but that's about it. Adults rely on agile flight to hunt nimble aerial prey with their spiked legs, while nymphs ambush aquatic prey with specialized mandibles that would make a xenomorph jealous. In other cases like the Hawaiian caterpillar, if I'm not mistaken, we have an adult stage that feeds on nectar while its caterpillar stage is an ambush hunter, meaning that, at least in insects, the presence of metamorphosis even allows for completely different diets between stages (this also applies to the more common leaf eating caterpillars and their nectar-feeding adult counterparts).

Given that, it's important to highlight one big difference regarding metamorphosis in frogs and in holometabolic insects: one grants a slight difference in lifestyle (fully aquatic to only partially aquatic, being in some ways closer to incomplete metamorphosis than it is to complete metamorphosis, especially since the frog itself never needs to turn into jelly or form a cocoon), while the other one is the one that allows for such drastic changes and the one I'm referring to in this. It's also important to be aware of 2 of the biggest problems of drastic, insect-style metamorphosis:

1- the very changes that allow for completely different lifestyles between ages requires A LOT of energy. Basically turning yourself into soup and then reforming your body takes a lot of energy to make, meaning you need to gather some good reserves and find a safe place to form the cocoon you'll be stuck in as a living puddle for a while, because
2- throughout this metamorphosis period the creature is completely defenseless apart from its cocoon.

Now, how do we add in more life stages? Simple: mix caterpillars, frogs an T-rexes. Recent studies show that apex predators like T-Rex and dunkleosteus changed quite a lot in theis development, with the fully grown adults usually hunting slower, tougher prey (or in the case of the dunkle, larger prey with harder shells too tough for the Jaws of the juveniles) while the juveniles were much more nimble, despite having a weaker jaw, hunting after relatively smaller, more nimble prey they adults couldn't hope to pursuit.

So basically, all we need to get our creature is mix the frog (or the dragonfly) and the T-Rex, or rather, one that basically undergoes both complete and incomplete metamorphosis.

Your creature could begin its lifestyle as an ambush predator adept at swimming, doted with the means to ambush prey underwater. After going through several growth stages and switching prey size underwater as it grows, it finally reaches a stage where it's got enough reserves, at which point it finds a safe place, enters a state of torpor and reaches its second form. In this new form however, rather than being a fully mature, fertile adult, it would be simply very similar to the adult version, but still lacking some of the adult qualities, potentially having a weaker jaw, a nimbler build or another group of differences big enough to allow for a lack of competition between both regarding prey type, but not too big for it to need to turn itself into jelly or grow extra limbs once again. The juvenile then begins its new pursuit predator stage while normally developing into its adult form, becoming more sluggish, but stronger, larger and bulkier. If such a lifestyle helped it survive when compared to others of its species that just underwent the first and last stage, it'd be selected, much like complete metamorphosis was selected in several insect species instead of only partial metamorphosis.

Summing up: to "add in" another stage, all you need is for the young form to reach a non-adult "mature" form. This non mature adult then undergoes incomplete metamorphosis turning into the fully grown adult. This is not too crazy to consider since, well, metamorphosis as is already exists and is much more drastic than incomplete metamorphosis. In insects, I've learned that the reason molting and overall growth in mature adults is usually not too common is simply because it's too "dangerous and unnecessary" (as in they've completely developed already, are ready to spread their genes and probably don't have much long left, especially in zones of the planet with harsher winters).

Comment: For many moths, the adult form doesn't even have a mouth! They exist solely to breed, and die shortly after finding a mate - if they find one. Then there are species that are kind of stuck with complete metamorphosis, despite no longer niche-portioning between young and old. Most beetles, for instance, as evidenced by the fact that their heads are "adult" from first hatch.